# Android NotificationBuilder - Cannot resolve method build

Tags: android

I had a perfectly working Notification segment in my app all this while. Recently I started using Google Cloud Storage  and so I made the following changes to my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.wu-man:android-oauth-client:0.0.3'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev17-1.19.0'
compile(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version:'1.19.0'){
    exclude(group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5')
}
```

That is precisely all that I modified, but now my `NotificationCompat.Builder.build()` and `NotificationCompat.Builder.setPriority()` cannot be resoled. All other functions like `setSound()` are working. It's just these two methods.

I tried to clean my project, rebuild it etc. I also restarted my PC, but can't get those two methods to be resolved.

What do I do, and why is this happening?

Comment: Are you importing the Support library?

Comment: I fear something has been corrupted. I looked up the actual NotificationCompat implementation file on my system and it doesn't contain those two methods.. How do I reset *whatever-you-think-has-been-corrupted?*

Comment: First, make sure that the Support library is up to date, might be that you're using an older version that doesn't have that code. If this is not the problem - you can just delete the library from local repo and re-download it through the SDK manager.

Comment: I updated it to the latest one.. Wait, I'll try to delete the lib.

Comment: Just tried.. No help there.. :/